# Why every firebase hosting project have the same IP address

Tags: firebase, dns, firebase-hosting

I am fairly new to firebase and I am curious on how things work under the hood. I now have two separate project on firebase, and on both of them U use Firebase Hosting. Both of them required me to create a DNS record into my hostname provider to redirect my hostname to google servers.

Alright, I got it. Google is hosting it, I've to create a DNS record to redirect my hostname to google server.

But the tricky part is that both of my project asked me to create the exact same record `A` with the IP `199.36.158.100`. I'm guessing that Google have somewhat of a "frontend" server. And they are redirecting trafic to the corresponding hosting project server but no, with my basic skills of the command `curl` I have not found any redirect. Wrong guess.

Then how do they know what should be rendered ? Do they use the hostname that you are requesting to determine which hosting project should be return ? But how is it returned if there is no redirection ?

Just for clarification, my domain name are properly linked to the correct project. I have no issue on that matter. I am asking how do it work as I'm curious.

Comment: Oh I just answered and Im seeing "Google Cloud Employee" lol, are you not the expect here. Should be asking you haha

Answer (score 0):

I think they have the similar structure like for apache or nginx. Where in apache you have vhosts connected to the specific domain and its folder. So the server would map all incoming domain requests to their allocated project.